# Microsoft EWS Push Notification Response Message

Tags: xml, exchangewebservices

We are currently using push notifications from Microsoft Exchange Web Services to call our service whenever a new calendar event is created. This seems to be working fine at first. We are getting the verification message and responding with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s= "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
      <SendNotificationResult xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
        <SubscriptionStatus>OK</SubscriptionStatus>
      </SendNotificationResult>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

Unfortunately exchange server just continues to send us the verification message at increasing intervals, as if our response is malformed. Does anyone know why Microsoft is not accepting our response message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your XML tag should be named `<SendNotificationResultType>` instead of `<SendNotificationResult>`.

Give that a try and let us know if you have any issues.