# EWS Push Subscription, how to know when it expires?

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am subscribing to EWS push notifications for calendar events using python. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd636171(v=exchg.80).aspx

When doing the same thing with google, you get an "expires" date in the first request, so you know when you need to renew the subscription.

How do I know when the EWS subscription is going to expire so I can renew?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real timeout property for push notifications. Exchange push notifications works in a slightly different way, as alluded to by the [time-out section in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_notifoperations):

> If the server does not receive a response to a push notification or
>   status ping, it retries sending the notification several times before
>   it stops sending the notifications.

So you do not subscribe for a set amount of time. You will get notifications as long as you respond to the server and acknowledge that you received the notification. The server will stop sending notifications to you when you stop sending [status pings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276678/microsoft-ews-push-notification-response-message) to every push notification.

How many times the Exchange server should retry and ask you for a `status ping` can be specified in the initial subscription request, with the [StatusFrequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564048(v=exchg.150).aspx)-element. You simply specify for how many minutes the server should ask you for an acknowledgement before giving up and stop pushing notifications to you.

[Webdav101's article on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2014/04/17/ews-push-what-is-the-statusfrequency-for.aspx) is really good, and he states that it is up to you to have some fallback code for when subscriptions stops for some reason. That could be handled by simply issuing a new push subscription if you have not received a notification for a while.